# systemd service on connected/not status of tunnel

Tags: systemd, network-interface, openvpn

I am using OpenVPN as a client on Ubuntu 22.04 without the persis-tun option. Thus, when OpenVPN server comes available, eventually OpenVPN will connect and create a tun0 device. When the server is not available, the tun0 interface is not available.

It seems to me I should be able to create a systemd service with either

```
[Unit]
After=sys-devices-virtual-net-tun0.device
```

or by adding

```
[Install]
WantedBy=sys-devices-virtual-net-tun0.device
```

or some combination of those options in my .service file

However, this seems to only fire the very first time on a system the tun0 interface becomes available. Whether the tunnel is up, or not, or openvpn is running, or not, `systemctl --all | grep tun0` will display both `sys-devices-virtual-net-tun0.device` and `sys-subsystem-net-devices-tun0.device` as loaded/active/plugged

What can I do to make my service's ExecStart fire every time the tun0 interface becomes available due to OpenVPN client reconnecting?